# Trouble in writing to Internal EEPROM- PIC16F684

Tags: c, pic, eeprom

In a Home security alarm system, we have a remote control armed with PT2440
with Fixed encoding (no hop coding, no encryption/decryption) and a central
receiver system armed with MCU: PIC16F684. I must use the internal EEPROM (256 bytes).
After a lot of programming and testing my problem reduced to: I can write to internal
memory before the main loop, but inside the main while loop, the write operation
failed. Here it is my main code

```
    //This function Writes data to given address in internal EEPROM of PIC MCU
    void internal_EEPROM_putc(unsigned char addr, unsigned char data)
    {
       unsigned char INTCON_SAVE;
       EEADR = addr;
       EEDATA = data;
       EEPGD = 0;            // 0 = Access data EEPROM memory
       WREN = 1;             // enable writes to internal EEPROM
       INTCON_SAVE = 0x9B;   // Save INTCON register contants
       GIE = 0;              // Disable interrupts, Next two lines SHOULD run without 
                             //  interrupts
       EECON2=0x55;
       EECON2=0xAA;
       WR = 1;    // begin write to internal EEPROM
       INTCON = INTCON_SAVE; //Now we can safely enable interrupts if previously used
       delay_cycles(1); // like NOP

       while(!WR) // Wait till write operation complete
           delay_cycles(1);
       WREN=0; // Disable writes to EEPROM on write complete (EEIF flag on set PIR2 )
    }
    // This function reads data from address given in internal EEPROM of PIC
    unsigned char internal_EEPROM_getc(unsigned char addr)
    {
       EEADR = addr;
       EEPGD= 0; // 0 = Access data EEPROM memory
       RD   = 1; // EEPROM Read
       return EEDATA;       // return data
    }

    void main()
    {
        // IT WORKS!
        internal_EEPROM_putc(0x12,0x34); //Write 0x34 to EEPROM address 0x12
        delay_cycles(1);
        c = internal_EEPROM_getc(0x12); // Read EEPROM address 0x12 in to variable C
        if (c != 0x34) { 
          RC1 = ON; // activate a relay, if read and write mismatches
          delay_ms(500);
          RC1 = OFF;
        } // there is no relay activation

        while (TRUE) {
           // IT DOESN'T WORK!
           internal_EEPROM_putc(0x13,0x56); //Write 0x34 to EEPROM address 0x12
           delay_cycles(1);
           c = internal_EEPROM_getc(0x13); // Read EEPROM address 0x12 in to variable C
           if (c != 0x56) {
             RC1 = ON;
             delay_ms(500);
             RC1 = OFF;
           } // no relay activation
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?
FYI, I use C programming language (not assembly), I use CCS C compiler (PCWHD) (4.057)
under Windows 7 (32 and 64 bits) and my programmer is PICKKit 2).

Comment: you intentionally assign `EECON2` two times `       EECON2=0x55;       EECON2=0xAA; ` ?

Comment: @fritzone Reading the datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41202F-print.pdf, page 77 this is necessary. So it will be intentionally in the code.

Comment: @fritzone. Yes that's true. and according to PIC16F684 it's required. Please see the [link](http://www.mcuexamples.com/PIC-internal-EEPROM.php)

Comment: On similar PIC, you have to set EEPGD to 1 to activate flashing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661845/writing-to-eeprom-on-pic?rq=1 . Also : http://www.phanderson.com/PIC/PICC/sourceboost/fl_ee2.html

Comment: @georgesl I don't think so. Actually the behavior of my program get worse.

Comment: Can you show the asm code?

Comment: There is no EEPGD register in PIC16F684! Check also the addresses of EEADR, EEDATA and other registers.

Comment: @SaeedAmrollahiBoyouki  Is it possible that over time you have exceeded the maximum number of write cycles that the EEPROM can take.  On PIC18F452 this number is 10000 (ten thousand), if I remember correctly.